Simple lua code does not run in Visual Studio Code
I have created a folder users>user_name>lua_tests in which I have saved the following simple code
A = {{1,2},{3,4}}

io.write(#A,"\n")

This executes successfully on a macOS terminal.
I have installed the following extensions:

Lua: Lua Language Server coded by Lua
Lua Debug: VSCode debugger extension for Lua
extensionPath

When I select Run File there is no response.
I am using lua 5.4 on a macOS 10.15.7. I use the same computer to run Python on VSCode without any problems.

Try reverting Lua Debug back to version 2.0.9. I also could not run Lua code with Lua Debug 2.0.10.

@DavidvonTamar thanks ; unfortunately it did not work. Maybe I have to try to reinstall Lua Debug and this time open the repository in VSCode and run task：Copy Publish. I did not have to do the same in windows.

@DavidvonTamar it works with 2.0.5 and without the extensionPath.
